# Como hacer una llamada ajax despues de seleccionar una opcion de combo box en angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

Este es mi html.

```
<div class="pull">
    <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectCuenta" ng-options="cuentas as cuentas.asociado for cuentas in ListaCuentas track by cuentas.id ">
        <option value="">Cuenta</option>
        <option value="">Cuenta1</option>
        <option value="">Cuenta2</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

Así es como obtengo la lista en mi service:

```
this.getCuentas = function () {
    return $http.get(UrlCuentas);
};
```

lo consumo en mi controler de la siguiente manera

```
$scope.status='';
$scope.selectCuenta =null;
productoServicio.getCuentas().then(function (response) {
    $scope.ListaCuentas  = response.data;
    //$scope.estado = true;     
}, function (error) {
    $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' +        error.message;
    // $scope.estado = false;     
});
```

Necesito llamar un JSON(ej: UrlRecibos) cuando por ejemplo selecciono "cuenta1" esto no se donde hacerlo si en el service o controller de mi aplicación Angular.

Tenía pensado hacerlo con un `ng-click` pero no sé como implementar la función. Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar soy nuevo en AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `ng-change`

> Evalúa la expresión dada cuando el usuario cambia el input. La expresión es evaluada inmediatamente, a diferencia del evento `onchange` de Javascript que sólo se desencadena al final del cambio (usualmente cuando el usuario sale del control o presiona la tecla return).

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hazAlgo = function() {
      alert('Valor cambiado');
      // Aqui haces la llamada ajax
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="pull">
    <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectCuenta" ng-change="hazAlgo()">
      <option value="">Cuenta</option>
      <option value="1">Cuenta1</option>
      <option value="2">Cuenta2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

O también puedes usar un `$watch`

> Registra un callback para ejecutarse cuando la expresión a observar cambia.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('selectCuenta', function() {
      alert('Valor cambiado');
      // aqui haces la llamada ajax
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="pull">
    <select name="ifield06" ng-model="selectCuenta">
      <option value="">Cuenta</option>
      <option value="1">Cuenta1</option>
      <option value="2">Cuenta2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ambos se desencadenaran cuando cambie el valor asociado al `ng-model`. Ten en cuenta que en tu ejemplo tu pones todos los atributos `value` de las etiquetas `<option>` igual al mismo valor lo cual causará que el valor sea siempre el mismo y no se detecte ningún cambio.

En lugar de

```
<option value="">Cuenta</option>
<option value="">Cuenta1</option>
<option value="">Cuenta2</option>
```

debería ser

```
<option value="">Cuenta</option>
<option value="1">Cuenta1</option>
<option value="2">Cuenta2</option>
```

o algo similar.

También fijate que quité `ng-options` de tu select ya que estas especificando las opciones manualmente usando elementos `<option>`. Puedes usar `ng-options` sin problemas pero debes escoger una de las dos vías pues de lo contrario todos los `<option>` que pongas serán sobreescritos por `ng-options` cuando el DOM se compile.

Comment: Muchas Gracias devconcept  por la ayuda,  si,  lo del value lo puse como ejemplo. Al final solo pinto lo que me envian en el array.

Comment: @jose.luis.lopez No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.